# Interpretation of Dirac equation states

Tags: wavefunction, dirac-equation

In Pauli theory the components of two-component wavefunction were interpreted as probability amplitudes of finding the particle in particular spin state. This seems easy to understand.

But when talking about Dirac equation, we have four-component wavefunction, two of which correspond to usual spin components of Pauli electron, and another two... How do I interpret positron-related components of Dirac electron? Are they probability amplitudes for the particle to appear to be positron? Or maybe to appear to *not* be positron (taking Dirac sea picture into account)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The interpretation of the Dirac equation states depend on what representation you choose for your $\gamma^\mu$-matrices or your $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$-matrices depending on what you prefer. Both are linked via $\gamma^\mu=(\beta,\beta\vec{\alpha})$. Choosing your representation will (more or less) fix your basis in which you consider the solutions to your equation (choosing another representation will rotate your entire solution).

The representation that I will choose is the Dirac-Pauli representation, given by:
$$\beta=\left(\begin{array}{c c}\mathbb{I}_{2\times2}&0\\0&-\mathbb{I}_{2\times2}\end{array}\right) \quad\text{and}\quad \alpha^i=\left(\begin{array}{c c}0&\sigma^i\\\sigma^i&0\end{array}\right),$$
where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli-matrices.

If you would solve the Dirac-equation in this representation, you will find [4 independent solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor):
$$
\psi_1(x)=N_1\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\\frac{p_z}{E+m}\\\frac{p_x+ip_y}{E+m}\end{array}\right)\exp(-ip_\mu x^\mu)
$$
$$
\psi_2(x)=N_2\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\\frac{p_x-ip_y}{E+m}\\\frac{-p_z}{E+m}\end{array}\right)\exp(-ip_\mu x^\mu)
$$
$$
\psi_3(x)=N_3\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{p_z}{E-m}\\\frac{p_x+ip_y}{E-m}\\1\\0\end{array}\right)\exp(ip_\mu x^\mu)
$$
$$
\psi_4(x)=N_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{p_x-ip_y}{E-m}\\\frac{-p_z}{E-m}\\0\\1\end{array}\right)\exp(ip_\mu x^\mu)
$$

The way to interpret these states is to look at them in the rest-frame, so the frame in which they stand still $p^\mu=(E,0,0,0)$, the states will become simply the following:
$$\psi_1=N_1\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)e^{-iEt}, \psi_2=N_2\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)e^{-iEt}, \psi_3=N_3\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)e^{iEt}\text{ and } \psi_4=N_4\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)e^{iEt},$$
by inspection of the time-evolution of the phase factor we can already see that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ represent positive energy states (particles) and the $\psi_3$ and $\psi_4$ represent negative energy states (so anti-particles).

In order to know the spin you should use the [helicity-operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics)), given by:
$$\sigma_p=\frac{\hat{\vec{p}}\cdot \hat{S}}{|\vec{p}|},$$
In the case of the Dirac-equation the spin operator is given by the double Pauli-matrix:
$$\hat{S}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}\vec{\sigma}&0\\0&\vec{\sigma}\end{array}\right),$$
if we let this one work on the spinors $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$, $\psi_3$ and $\psi_4$, we find that their spin is respectively up, down, up, down. So looking at electrons the Dirac-spinor can be interpreted in the Pauli-Dirac representation as (for example for the electron):
$$
\psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}e^-\uparrow\\e^-\downarrow\\e^+\uparrow\\e^+\downarrow\end{array}\right).
$$
When the momentum is NOT equal to zero these different states mix up and you can't make such a simple identification. Usually one says that the electron becomes a mixture of an electron with positrons when it starts moving.

Comment: How should a state of $\psi_1+\psi_3$ then be interpreted? Will a measurement find sometimes electron, other times positron?

Comment: @Ruslan, the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1+\psi_2)$, will be a superposition of a spin-up electron and a spin-down positron (in the rest-frame), so a measurement would indeed have a 50% chance to find a spin-up electron and a 50% chance to find a spin-up positron.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the Dirac representation is "the most common". The Chiral (or Weyl) representation
$$ \gamma^{\mu} = \left( \begin{array}{c c} 0_2 & \sigma^{\mu} \\ \bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0_2 \end{array} \right) $$
where
$$  \sigma^{\mu} = (I_2, \sigma^i) \quad \mbox{ and } \quad  \bar{\sigma}^{\mu} = (I_2, - \sigma^i) $$
with the $\sigma^i$ the usual Pauli matrices, is also very common.
As with the metric convention, it is an unfortunate case that everyone won't agree on.

Comment: @Nick I asked not about states $1$ and $2$, my question was about $1$ and $3$. $\psi_1+\psi_2$ is indeed quite obvious.

Comment: @Nick : Also, I believe that the subscript on that second $\psi$ should be a '3'.

Comment: @Ruslan, as Flint72 pointed out, I mad a typo, it's indeed the states $\psi_1$ and $\psi_3$ I was talking about.

Comment: @Flint72, Indeed both the Weyl and Dirac-Pauli are the most used, maybe it was wrong of me to say that Dirac is most used. I believe that in particle physics the Weyl-representation might be more used, but for an introduction the Dirac-Pauli is the typical choice (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Nick What makes me doubt in interpreting $\psi_{3,4}$ as positron probability is the following: in semiconductors, an electron in valence band is still an electron, even if its effective mass is negative and the energy (relative to center of band gap) is also negative, it's still not a hole. But if there's plenty of such electrons, then the not-filled states in valence band _are_ holes. It seems quite analogous with Dirac electrons. Shouldn't $\psi_{3,4}$ be states of _electrons_ in Dirac sea, and lack of such electrons be the positrons? Or is such analogy flawed?

Comment: @Ruslan 1) Bear in mind that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Psi_1+\Psi_3)$ isn't an eigenstate of the Dirac Hamiltonian, since one has energy>0 while the other <0. Their superposition is possible but undefined in the Hamiltonian basis.
2) Sure, $\Psi_{3,4}$ are electrons with energy<0. You may then interpret them as belonging to the Dirac sea, as Dirac did, and say that positrons are holes; or you may look at the conserved current and reinterpret them as positively charged states.In either way, you realize that the Dirac equation does admit energy<0 states for electrons. That was Pauli's concern,indeed.

Comment: @Ruslan, indeed in semi-conductors you also have electrons and holes, and if you want you can draw that kind of anology since a hole also acts like a positive charged particle, see also Wizzerad's comment! Because $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$, $\psi_3$ and $\psi_4$ all follow Dirac's equation we know it are particles with mass $m$ (so all the same mass), if you look at the charge you see that the charge of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ is opposite to that of $\psi_3$ and $\psi_4$ (you can do this by symmetry, or by calculating the probability density and interpreting this as a charge distribution as Pauli did).