# Matching Dirac/Majorana/Weyl Spinor Degrees of Freedom in Minkowski signature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, representation-theory, spinors

Question: How do we match the real degrees of freedom (DOF) of Dirac/Majorana/Weyl Spinor 
in terms of their quantum numbers (spin, momentum, etc) [in any dimensions [1+1 to 9+1] in Minkowski signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Summary_in_low_dimensions)?

[image]

(p.s. This question is partially inspired by this [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357206/), but I am asking something more generally in any dimensions from 1+1 to 9+1 in Minkowski signature)

My question concerns that how to match each component of spinors in physical degrees of freedom (real degrees of freedom of Dirac/Majorana/Weyl Spinor) reflecting into their quantum numbers.

For example in 3+1d, in Weyl basis,

> For 3+1d Dirac spinor,

we have 4 component complex spinor thus we have 8 real degrees of freedom. For the massless particles, in the boost limit along the $z$ direction, $p_z \to E$ or $p_z \to -E$, we can match

> $$
> 8=2 \times 2 \times 2, 
> $$
>   as
>   $$
> 8 \text{ real DOF}= 2 \text{ (spin up/down)} \times 2 \text{ (momentum up/down)}
> \times 2 \text{ (particle/ anti-particle)}
> $$
>   More precisely, the 8 real DOF becomes the following:

$\psi_{par}(x)=u(p) e^{-ip \cdot x}=u(p) e^{-i (Et -\vec{p}  \cdot \vec{x})}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \zeta^s \\
\sqrt{p \cdot \bar{\sigma}} \zeta^s 
\end{pmatrix} e^{-i (Et -\vec{p}  \cdot \vec{x})}$, $s=1,2$

$\psi_{anti}(x)=v(p) e^{ip \cdot x}=v(p) e^{i (Et -\vec{p}  \cdot \vec{x})}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \eta^s \\
-\sqrt{p \cdot \bar{\sigma}} \eta^s 
\end{pmatrix} e^{i (Et -\vec{p}  \cdot \vec{x})}$, $s=1,2$

particle, $p_3=p_z=E$, spin up,

$\psi_{par}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-ip \cdot x}$

particle, $p_3=p_z=E$, spin down,

$\psi_{par}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-ip \cdot x}$

particle, $p_3=p_z=-E$, spin up,

$\psi_{par}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-ip \cdot x}$

particle, $p_3=p_z=-E$, spin down,

$\psi_{par}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-ip \cdot x}$

anti-particle, $p_3=p_z=E$, spin up,

$\psi_{anti}(x)= 
-\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{ip \cdot x}$

anti-particle, $p_3=p_z=E$, spin down,

$\psi_{anti}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{ip \cdot x}$

anti-particle, $p_3=p_z=-E$, spin up,

$\psi_{anti}(x)= 
\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{ip \cdot x}$

anti-particle, $p_3=p_z=-E$, spin down,

$\psi_{anti}(x)= 
-\sqrt{2E} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
e^{ip \cdot x}$

---

> For 3+1d Weyl spinor,

we separate Dirac into left-hand and right-hand Weyl spinors, thus

We have the particle is the same as the anti-particle, which is the real representation. Thus we have

for left-handed ($P_L$)

> $$
> 4=(2) \times 2, 
> $$
>   as
>   $$
> 4 \text{ real DOF}= (2 \text{( $-1/2$ helicity : spin up/down lock momentum up/down)}
> \times 2 \text{ (particle / anti-particle)}
> $$

similarly 
for right-handed ($P_R$)

> $$
> 4=(2) \times 2, 
> $$
>   as
>   $$
> 4 \text{ real DOF}= 2 \text{($+1/2$ helicity : spin up/down lock momentum up/down)}
> \times 2 \text{ (particle / anti-particle)}
> $$

---

> For 3+1d Majorana spinor,

We have the particle is the same as the anti-particle, which is the real representation. Thus we have

> $$
> 4=2 \times 2 \times 1, 
> $$
>   as
>   $$
> 4 \text{ real DOF}= 2 \text{ (spin up/down)} \times 2 \text{ (momentum up/down)}
> \times 1 \text{ (particle = anti-particle)}
> $$

**How about other dimensions?**

There will be certainly an even-odd dimensions subtlty. Also the the helicity like degrees of freedom (the spin projected along the boost direction) may NOT be enough for other dimensions higher than 3+1d.